# count how many objects created by class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

attach sample code in Java below:

```
class Test { 
    static int noOfObjects = 0; 
    { 
        noOfObjects += 1; 
    } 
    public Test() {        
         // ....
    } 
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
    Test t1 = new Test(); 
    Test t2 = new Test(5); 
    Test t3 = new Test("GFG"); 
    System.out.println(Test.noOfObjects);       // ans will be 3
    } 
}
```

can we code it in JavaScript??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that can be done in Javascript.

Just increase a static counter in the constructor for the class.

```js
class Test { 
    static noOfObject = 0;
    constructor() {
      Test.noOfObject += 1;
      // ....
    } 
} 

const t1 = new Test(); 
const t2 = new Test(5); 
const t3 = new Test("GFG"); 
console.log(Test.noOfObject);
```